# Display range of week numbers based on quarter

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

A year has 4 quarters. If I choose a quarter, I would like to get a list of the Week Numbers for that quarter.

I know I can use `WEEKNUM` to get the week number of a date (and optional parameter to indicate Week begins on a Monday).

My goal is to use that as a list in a Data Validation dropdown element. If I can output the range in cells I can easily use that for reference.

In short I need to be able to create a range of numbers between two values.

For example; if given these two numbers, 12 and 24:

How could I populate a range of cells with *12, 13, 14, 15*, and so on, through to *24*.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
=SEQUENCE(1; 13; 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I figured it out:

```
=TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(Row(12:24)))
```